# gnuplot - How to plot data in different lines and rows?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to analyze a file, which has text and data.

Basically I have multiple lines; each one has a specific element, and the tests done increase or decrease the amount (I will avoid to go into specific details about the meaning of the data), so we can get a reaction time as result.

Each element will have multiple entry, since the amount will change, so my data file will have multiple entry, like this:

```
element    "grade1"    amount    .4532    reactiontime    .011432
element    "test2"     amount    .2322    reactiontime    .003214
element    "enriched"  amount    .4432    reactiontime    .002443
element    "grade1"    amount    .2532    reactiontime    .018432
element    "test2"     amount    .3322    reactiontime    .006214
element    "enriched"  amount    .1432    reactiontime    .012443
element    "grade1"    amount    .1532    reactiontime    .016432
element    "test2"     amount    .4322    reactiontime    .003114
element    "enriched"  amount    .2432    reactiontime    .002643
```

I am trying to achieve this:

1) I would like to plot the numbers at position #4 and #6, using as caption the text at position #3 and #5, for each line of the same element. In this way I can have on the same graph the various elements, each with their own style.

2) use the text at position #2, as name for the graph

I've tried to look at the single commands; and I've found somehow how to differentiate the name with "set title", but I am not sure how you grab specific entry on the same line, and how you specify a line, when a file has more than one.

Any suggestion is more than appreciated.

Comment: Your data structure does not make a lot of sense, as three of the columns seem completely obsolete. Normally I would create four files, with two columns.

Comment: The data is purely fictional, it is mainly to show what kind of data structure I have. So you would suggest to group them by element, and make N different file...one for each element?

Comment: If you have the choice, yes. In my opinion that makes more sense AND occupies less disk space (if the file become large)

Comment: I see; the issue is that I have about 150 elements, and I was hoping that I could reduce the amount of files generated, saving all on a single file, and grabbing only what I need. Every day the file is deleted and a new one starts, that's why I set up the file output to be like that. I can make temp files using awk or sed, with just the data related to each element thou; and load them dynamically into gnuplot...that may resolve the issue of having more than a hundred files

Comment: Of course it is possible, but than still I would use header element, amount and reaction time, or does that also change (this is not clear from your example file). If something does not change, don't store it as a column

Comment: Basically what changes is the element name (string), the reaction time and the amount (both double); the other 3 are the headers. I was able to find how you select a column, but I can't find yet a way to select rows. Nor I can understand how you read a value different from a number; since seems that the title property accept only strings, and references like $2 won't work.